# How to make completely custom authentication/authorization without asp membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I wan't to learn how to make completely custom authentication/authorization for asp mvc.
So simple actions: **Register/Login/Logout/Remeber Me**.
I don't want to use asp membership any more but I can't find any from start to end tutorial on the web on how to make this.
I am and a little confused. If I make everything custom do I need still use `SetAuthCookie()` etc. 
So I don't want customize `MembershipProvider` but to make my own authorization/authentication.
All I am looking for is some complete resource (if exists)?
I really need help on this topic so I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest doing some reading into how the asp.net membership API works before attempting to write your own.

Comment: But why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do this.

The problem with developing your own membership classes is that 99.999% of the time you won't have the security knowledge to make a safe, secure, robust and reliable framework. (The other 0.001% of the time you are an expert being employed by a third party to do just that.)

I know that MembershipProvider is clunky, bloated and not as flexible as it perhaps should be. But it is pretty secure, and a heck of a lot more secure than anything you can write. It isn't worth the risk... In developing your own you risk losing control of your site, your data, and most importantly your clients' data.

Stick with it. You will be sorry otherwise.

Comment: I disagree. Though rewriting the *authentication* portions of ASP.NET membership is a risky venture, there is a **lot** to the framework other than the authentication. Is the data layer used to fetch passwords really anywhere near as critical as the mechanism that subsequently validates the user if that password check passes?

Comment: Ok the thing why I wanted to do this is because I get some advice that it's bad to make join to aspnet_Users table from my Users table (not sure why). And this question is related to this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920327/how-to-join-aspnet-user-to-my-custom-user

Comment: Is it really bad to join my custom user table to aspnet_Users and make 1:1 relation between them?

Comment: @Snixtor - We are not talking about extending (which is encouraged with the framework) but about rewriting. I strongly feel that rewriting what he wishes to rewrite (based on the question) is a bad idea.

Comment: You don't need to necessarily use the aspnet_Users table. I recommend that you look into **extending** the ASP.NET membership framework. There are plenty of articles on the web explaining how you can go about this. You can do things like override `ValidateUser`, for example, which will allow you to specify your own logic for determining whether a given user is valid or not.

Comment: Ok, then I will try to implement custom membership. Thanks for pointing me.

Comment: @1110 if you want to have direct access into tables directly I recommend you to use simplemembership instead of the old membership provider. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx . same thing if you need to have customer fields instead of blobs in profile and more...

Comment: I have already implemented custom membership with help of this guide: http://ashuthinks.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same idea that @levibotelho, is not secure if you are not 100% sure. on the other hand you can find many projects in http://nugetmusthaves.com/Category/Security
examples are: http://altairiswebsecurity.codeplex.com/, https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity and more...

probably this one: https://github.com/OdeToCode/Memflex 
brgds!.

update: @1110 if you want to have direct access into tables I recommend you to use simplemembership instead of the old membership provider. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx . same thing if you need to have customer fields instead of blobs in profile and more...

Answer (score 1):

First, a crash course in ASP.NET membership and Forms Authentication.

Straight from the provider ([Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

*"ASP.NET membership gives you a built-in way to validate and store user credentials. ASP.NET membership therefore helps you manage user authentication in your Web sites. You can use ASP.NET membership with ASP.NET forms authentication by using with the ASP.NET login controls to create a complete system for authenticating users."*

Note that you *"can use ASP.NET membership with ASP.NET forms authentication"*. They are distinct elements. The authentication portion is something you don't want to mess with, and this is the part I think LeviBotelho is (rightly) nervous about. But you can just as rightly use forms authentication without membership!

As [Scott Mitchell points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638694/855363), prior to ASP.NET 2.0, we didn't even *have* `Membership`. His own (admittedly quite old now) [article over on 4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043732/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.aspx) offers an example of role-based authorization, combining Forms Authentication and **not** using `Membership`. There isn't anything inherently insecure or risky about this.

If you *are* venturing away from the `Membership` pattern / framework though, the next most important thing to get right is password security. Your first temptation might be to store user passwords as plain-text in your database. **Don't.** Troy Hunt writes great articles on Internet security, and explains the ins and outs of password security far better than I could. [This article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) goes into much more detail than you might be interested in (it's primarily about creating a password reset feature), but the starting points on password storage are very valid.

Regarding *"All I am looking for is some complete resource (if exists)?"*. You're probably not going to find such an article. This is a very broad topic, at best you'll find articles that each offer a little bit to help you develop your *own* solution.